# Magento simple product custom options add qty

Tags: magento

I have a Magento shop with 218 products.

All of them is created as a simple product with custom options like colour and sizes. What I now realized is that I should have used configurable product instead of simple product for controling the amout of qty of each product.

What I wanna know: Is there any way I can add qty to my custom options? Like this:

```
Black 2 qty
Yellow 5 qty
Red 3 qty
```

And so on?

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I found this guide: http://bhaskarchoubisa.blogspot.dk/2013/04/add-qty-box-in-custom-option-row-magento.html but I can't seem to get it to working.

Comment: This extension will allow you to add QTY to custom options of simple product - http://www.itoris.com/magento-dynamic-product-options.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple quantities of different simple products in the same add to cart click,  you will need to use Bundle products.  Configurable products are the norm for clothing however these do not give you the ability to add different quantities of the simple associated items.

You can add qty to custom options through custom functionality, however this is not the best solution

With a configurable product, you are selling one product with a selection of specific attributes.

With a bundle product, you are offering different products for sale under one parent, however allowing a quantity increment of each simple product.

Hope this helps!!  Thanks